# c++ login system fails when it s not the first element of stl vector

Tags: c++, c++14

I m trying to create a login system but I encounter an issue at login.
If it's the first person from the vector the login is successful otherwise the login is failed.
Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using std::string; using std::cin; using std::cout; using std::endl;
std::ofstream out("login_data.txt",std::ios::app);
std::ifstream in("login_data.txt");
class Person {
private:
    string nume;
    string parola;
public:
    void setNume(string nume) {
        this->nume = nume;
    }
    void setParola(string parola) {
        this->parola = parola;
    }
    Person(string nume, string parola) {
        this->nume = nume;
        this->parola = parola;
    }
    Person() {
        nume = "";
        parola = "";
    }
    string getNume() { return nume; }
    string getParola() { return parola; }
    bool equalTo(Person p) {
        if (this->nume == p.nume && this->parola == p.parola) {
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
};

std::vector<Person> persoane;
void printPers() {
    for (int i = 0; i < persoane.size()-1; i++) {
        cout << persoane.at(i).getNume() << " " << persoane.at(i).getParola();
    }
}
void registerPerson()
{
    string n;
    string p;
    cout << "Enter name:"; cin >> n;
    cout << "Enter password:"; cin >> p;
    out <<endl<< n << " " << p<<",";
}
void savePerson()
{
    string line;
    char delim =',';
    while (std::getline(in, line, delim)) {
        Person pers;
        string delimiter = " ";
        size_t pos = 0;
        string token;
        while ((pos = line.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos) {
            token = line.substr(0, pos);
            pers.setNume(token);
            line.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
        }
        pers.setParola(line);
        persoane.push_back(pers);
    }
}
bool checkLogin() {
    savePerson();
    string username;
    string userPassword;
    Person user;
    cout << "Specify the name:"; cin >> username;
    cout << "Specify password:"; cin >> userPassword;
    user.setNume(username);
    user.setParola(userPassword);
    for (int i = 0; i < persoane.size() - 1; i++) {
        if (user.equalTo(persoane.at(i)))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
}
int main()
{
    
    int choice;
    cout << "Enter option\n1.Register\n2.Login\nYour choice:";
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice == 1) {
        registerPerson();
    }
    else if (choice == 2) {
        if (!checkLogin()) {
            cout << "Login failed";
        }
        else {
            cout << "Login succesful";
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "Error please select a valid option.";
            exit(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the text file contains:

```
a b,
c d,
e f,
g h,
i j,
```

I also checked and the vector saves the Person objects properly,but for some reason in the checkLogin() method the problem occurs.

Comment: what do you expect `else { return false; }`  to do?

Comment: The `savePerson` function is rather badly named, as it doesn't save anything to a file. It does quite the opposite, read from a file.

Comment: Other issues include opening the same file as different objects, without any synchronization between them. And the loop condition `i < persoane.size()-1` which will skip the last element of the vector. And in the `savePerson` function you could simplify the code separating the username from the password using a simple `istringstream` and the `>>` stream extraction operator. Also, if you have `if (condition) { return true; } else { return false; ]` then it could be replaced with `return condition;`

Comment: `std::any_of` exists if you want to check if anything in a container fulfills the predicate (passed lambda),

Comment: It helped a lot ,thanks ,also i m not so used with the streams ,never used them ,lambda as well ,i m currently trying to learn more though those kind of projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```cpp
else {
    return false;
}
```

You want to `continue` the loop. Your function fails because of a premature return.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I immediately changed return false with the condition and now it all works!